# How to generate data in an Alembic migration i.e --autogenerate

Tags: python, sql, database, alembic

I can successfully generate a database model, however I can't seem to figure out how to populate the database with data.

I believe the error lies in the command I used to autogenerate

```
alembic -x data=true upgrade head
```

does not produce any data, though after looking at my generated file, there is nothing in data_upgrade() or data_downgrade().

The command I am using to generate an auto migration is

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "migration_objective"
```

This then upgrades head to what is expected, but with no data in any of the tables.

Am I missing an option flag? I can't seem to find documentation on additional flags to use at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

[Alembic AutoGenerate will not detect data changes](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect).

You'll need to pull the data out of the database to something like a CSV file which you can then parse and insert to the database during your upgrade

Comment: Not changes per se, initialization is what I'm looking for.
The only method I have of creating multiple test db's on the fly is using Alembic to create the structure then using sqldump to restore as a backup copy.

This isn't bad, but it'd be nice to roll into one migration script without manually inputting data under data_upgrade().

I didn't see mention of Alembic being able to parse .csv data, is this a feature?

Comment: @Lukabratzee Unfortunately, no, nothing like that is built into alembic. If you're looking for something more dynamic than a csv file or sqldump you could leverage sqlalchemy. [inspector](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector) can help dynamically create the ddl and you could also create functions to query the data from the original tables and insert into the new tables